# Sentry docker bad gateway after few days up

Tags: docker

I recently tried to install Sentry with the onpremise docker-compose file. https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise

I also use traefik with 2 network, here is an extract of my docker-compose after modifications to explain things:

```
services:
  web:
    << : *sentry_defaults
    # I use traefik, so I do not need to open a port
    #ports:
    #  - '9000:9000/tcp'
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.sentry.entryPoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.sentry.rule=Host(`sentry.me`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.sentry.tls=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
      - "traefik.http.routers.sentry.tls.certresolver=me"
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
      - sentry_platform
  cron:
    << : *sentry_defaults
    command: run cron
    networks:
      - sentry_platform
networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external:
      name: traefiknekland_default
  sentry_platform:
    external: false
    driver: bridge
```

The problem is that sometimes sentry is a bad gateway. Sometimes it's up for a few days then again a bad gateway.

Comment: I've been having the same problem (onpromise Sentry with Docker Compose and Traefik2) for a long time as well, haven't figured out yet. I've been running version 9 for couple of years and just upgraded to latest version (20 I believe), hopefully I won't have the same problem.